# Xamarin.Android BINDINGSGENERATOR warning "[Interface] in [Method] has 'unnamed' parameters"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

So, I have lots of the following warnings:

```
"[Interface] in [Method] has 'unnamed' parameters"
```

Is there any ideas how to get rid of those ?

Comment: Are you using a JavaDoc to name the parameters in your binding? If so, it could be the issue discussed here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17281

Comment: no, because it doesn't work as expected, we have our own parser which generates attributes for Metadata.xml